# Spring Data JPA with Hibernate, Delete an entity has a (ManyToOne), failed

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa

class ResourceFile

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }
```

Class Resouce

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "resource", orphanRemoval = true)
public List<ResourceFile> getResourceFiles() {
    return resourceFiles;
}

public void setResourceFiles(List<ResourceFile> resourceFiles) {
    this.resourceFiles = resourceFiles;
}
```

Try to use ResourceFileRepository(Spring data JPA).delete(id) to delete a ResourceFile, nothing happened, the server side just logged two select sql.

Why does that happen?

Comment: Can you also show the specific code that is performing the Delete?

Comment: It is very simple, just define a ResourceFileRepository interface extends PagingAndSortingRepository. and use ResourceFileRepository::delete function.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors or exceptions?

Comment: Show us the relevant code.